# How to make a computed column a persisted one?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to create an auto-generated customer id whenever a new customer is registered. The customer id should be in the following format

```
 Customer ID = 
   current year (4 digit) + 
   current month (2 digit) +
   unique number (4 digit).
```

Example: `2012055001`

I have written a query as follows:

```
create table tb
(
     id int identity(1000, 1),
     cust_id as CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())) + 
                SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112), 5, 2) + 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), id) persisted primary key
);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Computed column 'cust_id' in table 'tb' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: `GETDATE` is non-deterministic, so you cannot use it in this context. So, do this is a trigger as @KenWhite suggests, or construct the value in a variable before the insert.

Comment: @KenWhite you should make that an answer.

Comment: What happens when you get 1,0001 new customers in a month? Don't do it. Your internal table customer id should be an identity and your 'visual' customer number can then be generated as you've described.

Comment: At least base the key on the legitimate join date, which should already be in an existing column, rather than `GETDATE()`

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing **structure** with **data**. You're trying to create your table with **data** as the **structure** type, and that clearly can't work.

The column name would be `cust_id`, but the column type has to be one of the valid SQL Server data types (in this case most likely CHAR(10), as it's a fixed width and there are no Unicode characters possible).

```
CREATE TABLE tb(id int identity(1000, 1), cust_id Char(10));
```

Your auto-generated data would then be inserted into the column, most likely by an `ON INSERT` trigger. (How to create that trigger is a totally different topic; you can find information in most SQL tutorials or books, or in SQL Server documentation.)